# How to draw a rectangle on chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to create black rectangle on my chart like below;

[image]

Below code draws a line, not rectangle.

```
SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

    private void ugTopActivity_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var rect = new RectangleF(0,0, 200, 200);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rect);
    }
```

It's because my x-axis is shows the time not an integer value.

The result is ( Green Borders );

[image]

How can i make this happen ?

Comment: Unlike `DrawRectangle` which only draws the borders, `FillRectangle` draws a filled rectangle. Are you sure it isn't actually draws rectangle, but because the you may set the starting points in the start you can actually see the entire rectangle ? try shifting the starting points by couple of pixels to see it. And if you want a filled rectangle use the `FillRectangle` method.

Comment: @OrelEraki edited question using fillRecct

Comment: ugTopActivity either has controls on top of it...or has other things painted on top of it...i think we'll need the rest of the code to determine what to do

Comment: You need to decide on the coordinate calculation method! There are 3 (!!!) types in a chart: pixels, values and percentages. What do you need? You can convert between them with the axes functions..